# How to encode space as %20 in UrlEncodedFormEntity while executing apache HttpPost?

Tags: android, apache, encoding, httpclient, url-encoding

The web serive i am hitting requires the parameters as URLEncodedFormEntity. I am unable to change space to %20 as per requirement of the web service, instead space is converted to +.

My code is :

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient()
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters,
            HTTP.UTF_8);
post.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse resp = client.execute(post);
```

where parameters is `List<NameValuePair>` parameters.

I read through many posts and all suggest manuall change space to %20 after emcoding. Here, how do i access the entity and change it manually?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The UrlEncodedFormEntity is basically a StringEntity with a custom constructor, you don't actually have to use it in order to create a usuable entity.

```
String entityValue = URLEncodedUtils.format(parameters, HTTP.UTF_8);
// Do your replacement here in entityValue
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(entityValue, HTTP.UTF_8);
entity.setContentType(URLEncodedUtils.CONTENT_TYPE);
// And now do your posting of this entity
```

Comment: thanks for the response.. could you help me out a little bit here ? suppose i need to send a name value pair: itemName = Potato Chips  
How exactly would i need to modify and add this to the entity ?

Comment: Try adding a new BasicNameValuePair with "itemName" and "Potato Chips" to parameters, and then do a entityValue.replaceAll("\\+","%20"); where I wrote // Do your replacement here in entityValue.

Comment: Actually, you can use [URLEncoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html) to encode each value of parameters before using them in entity creation.

Comment: fyi: URLEncoder will however substitute HSPACE with +, as Rahul wanted to avoid - so you'd still be left with the task to replace these with %20.

Answer (score 0):

Jens' answer works like a charm!. To complete his example this what I was using to post a parameter:

```
String label = "A label";

List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("label", label));
httpget.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));
```

But it always posts the "+" string, I mean, "label=A+label". Using Jens' suggestion I changed my code to:

```
String label = "A label";

List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("label", label));

String entityValue = URLEncodedUtils.format(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8);
entityValue = entityValue.replaceAll("\\+", "%20");

StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(entityValue, HTTP.UTF_8);
stringEntity.setContentType(URLEncodedUtils.CONTENT_TYPE);

httpget.setEntity(stringEntity);
```

Now it posts "label=A%20label"